# How to remove the default add to cart option and select option in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to remove the default add to cart button and select option and use the other one. Can anyone help it out. Screenshot is below...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8bOk.png)

Comment: This is my function.php code have look over it. Screenshot1:-https://i.stack.imgur.com/7US2x.png, Screenshot 2 ---https://i.stack.imgur.com/3R4Cx.png

Answer (score 0):

Use these hooks to remove add to cart option , you can place the code in functions.php

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart');
```